# How to query document by nested relations?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, relationship

I have Folder, Video and Access collections in my MongoDB database.
Folder can have few Video(one-to-many) and Video can have few Access(one-to-many).
I want to find Folders where Videos have specific Access in it.

I used `$elemMatch` like `Folder.find({videos: {$elemMatch: {access: {$in: <AccessInstance>}}}})`
and then also tried following technic `Folder.find({"videos.access": {$in: <AccessInstance>}})`
but neither of them worked for me.

Below is my model structure and relations:

```
@Schema()
export class Folder {
    _id: string;
 
  @Prop({ type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Video' })
  videos: Video[];
 
  // other properties..

}
```

---

```
@Schema()
export class Video{
    _id: string;
 
  @Prop({ type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Access' })
  access: Access[];
 
  // other properties..

}
```

---

```
@Schema()
export class Access{
    _id: string;
 
  // other properties..

}
```

What is the solution of this kind of task in Mongoose ?

Comment: Actually, you did it right but need to check _id in the access class, so 'access._id' filtering would be correct like this: Folder.find({videos: {$elemMatch: {"access._id": {$in: <AccessInstance>}}}}) I tested it for you, you can review it here as well: https://mongoplayground.net/p/K01_hsheJLf . About the other filtering you need to use the "$" tag to find the first matched element in the array so it should be like this: Folder.find({"videos.$.access._id": {$in: <AccessInstance>}}).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately this syntax is not working for documents that is been related with MongoDB Object id.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work since it checks the string with objectId. So, you just need to convert string filters to objectId then it works wel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems with your Schemas. You are defining the `_id` fields as `_id: string;` in all 3 Schemas but then referencing them as `ObjectId` such as `{ type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Video' }`. These are not comparable without a workaround.

Since you seem to be using Nest.js with mongoose  my advice would be to remove the `_id` field definition from each of your Schemas. Unless you want to define the `_id` fields as anything other than an `ObjectId` of course but I presume you don't. Mongoose will automatically define `_id` for you as an `ObjectId` so you can just delete those lines.

With that change in place in order to find a `Folder` that has `Videos` with specific `Access` in it you would need to use aggregate to do a `$lookup` of the `videos` array. That will then allow you to search the `videos.access` array for a match. Without that `$lookup` the `access` array has no context inside each `videos` array element. In other words, the `access` array doesn't exist yet in each `Folder` document.

Given an `Access` document that has the following `_id` value:

```js
const access = { _id: ObjectId("650ecb80507561a33ce927a5") }
```

Your aggregate will be:

```js
Folder.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "videos",
      "localField": "videos",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "videos"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "videos.access": ObjectId("650ecb80507561a33ce927a5")
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qhbBUk6o5qo) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. _id field is there for swagger documentation.
Your solutions is worked for me and I will mark it as right answer. But my schemas more complex than example here. And when I try to populate nested documents with $lookup operator it is being really headache. Is there elegant solutions for population of related documents other than $lookup operator ?

Comment: Yes you can use mongoose [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method which is incredibly handy. The only downside is that you can't filter parent document based on a condition in the child document. So in your case if you wanted a Folder that has a specific video the populate won't help because it's done after you look for a Folder condition. I would encourage you to look into aggregate more if your documents are complicated. It has so many features and is designed to transform your documents in endless ways. Just post another question if you get stuck.